# CSS underline element only if it is within span

Tags: html, css

Please see below:

```
<span class="caption">
{block:Caption}<p>{Caption}</p><hr>{/block:Caption}
 </span>
```

The Caption block will contain text, part of which is a link.  How do I create CSS that will underline the link within the "caption" span only?

Comment: ?? are you wrapping a p inside a span ? **Do not !**,use a div to make this HTML valid. beside can you set a plain HTML example of your structure so we do see your issue. Link are by defaut underlined , so what is your real trouble here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you can't have inline element around block element.

Than just do `a{text-decoration: none;} .caption a{text-decoration: underline}`

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery:

```
$(document).find('span.caption').each(function(){
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
})
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qq4j5uz2/

Comment: Why you need jQuery for CSS apply?

Comment: @Justinas Good point... I just tried to reply quickly while being focused to jQuery :) My bad!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly it would be something like this:

```
.caption a{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is also the :not() selector to filter tags to select:

example with links and valid HTML:

```css
li:not(.nop) a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
    <li class="nop"><a href="#nowhere" title="keep it underlined">Do not touch my underline defaut </a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```